# I have deployed my Yii app on Amazon WebServices but Yii:app()->params is empty

Tags: amazon-web-services, yii

I have deployed my Yii 1.1 app on AWS, but of some reason my Yii::app()->params is empty - and therefore parts of my app that use Yii app params is not working...
i have checked my main.php and there are no peculiarities.
Has anyone had this issue?

Comment: Is it working in non-AWS environment, e.g. localhost or elsewhere?

Comment: Check if params.php is in .gitignore file. It could be there for security reasons.

Comment: Do you have your app params on your config/main.php file or in other related location?

Comment: @AlejandroQuiroz Yes - it is in my main.php file

Comment: @shishir - on my localhost it works  fine

Comment: @bfcm - it is not in a params.php file, it is in main.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out my error... for some reason, my params array got nested under the modules array in my main.php file!  Therefore, Yii could not find it! Make sure params is not nested!
Arg!!!